# How to get the Rows Count in datagrid rather than datasource or datatable when using autogenerated?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

there is no rows be selected in intelligent menu after type rows after datagrid name

```
<StackPanel>
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="dgStatus" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  RenderTransformOrigin="-23.633,-5.198" Height="364" Width="811" 
                  CellEditEnding="myGrid_CellEditEnding" >
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Name="button1" Click="button1_Click" Height="50" Width="100"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide more details and fix your image problem

Comment: I dont understand why would you want that?

Comment: How about learning Bindings first then binding the Items.Count property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(dal.getNumOfRows("Table1")< dgStatus.Items.Count)
```